# fetch the dynamic value from json response using regex or json extractor in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

From the following JSON response, want to fetch the value `ref_id` of both the `type` (now here the catch is the `type` place is dynamic), how to extract it using JSON or REGEX extractor or using post processer.

So if you see there are two `ref_id`, one is under `metaData` and one is under `key`. Want to select the which is under the meta data
for example `for "type": "recall"` the `ref_id` is `cmVjYWxsLWU1ZGY4MTZkLTE0MTctNGJhNy1hMTQzLTY1OGJmMmYxYTRjMw==` and `for "type": "followUp"` is `Zm9sbG93VXAtMzk4MGRhZDQtOGE3Mi00YmM0LWFhYWEtM2Y3ZTU3NzZlNDM0`.

And the position of  `"type": "recall"` and `"type": "followUp"` is not constant in the json response. So I cannot use any constant index value to fetch this two value. Tried with `"id": "(.*?)","type": "recall"` and `"id": "(.*?)","type": "followUp"`. But it is failing.

```
{
    "entities": {
        "cmVjYWxsLWU1ZGY4MTZkLTE0MTctNGJhNy1hMTQzLTY1OGJmMmYxYTRjMw==": {
            "ref_id": "cmVjYWxsLWU1ZGY4MTZkLTE0MTctNGJhNy1hMTQzLTY1OGJmMmYxYTRjMw==",
            "type": "recall",
            "metaData": {
                "ref_id": "e5df816d-1417-4ba7-a143-658bf2f1a4c3",
                "accountId": "ef757dba-f0d5-4464-a338-4a810e02bf47",
                "patientId": "e74a1b0f-d3e0-4b78-bc4b-83687786466e",
                "timelineDate": "2021-01-30T14:28:24.738Z"
            }
        },
        "Zm9sbG93VXAtMzk4MGRhZDQtOGE3Mi00YmM0LWFhYWEtM2Y3ZTU3NzZlNDM0": {
            "ref_id": "Zm9sbG93VXAtMzk4MGRhZDQtOGE3Mi00YmM0LWFhYWEtM2Y3ZTU3NzZlNDM0",
            "type": "followUp",
            "metaData": {
                "ref_id": "3980dad4-8a72-4bc4-aaaa-3f7e5776e434",
                "patientId": "e74a1b0f-d3e0-4b78-bc4b-83687786466e",
                "createdAt": "2021-01-29T14:36:15.127Z",
                "timelineDate": "2021-01-29T14:36:15.127Z"
            }
        }
    },
    "result": [
        "cmVjYWxsLWU1ZGY4MTZkLTE0MTctNGJhNy1hMTQzLTY1OGJmMmYxYTRjMw==",
        "Zm9sbG93VXAtMzk4MGRhZDQtOGE3Mi00YmM0LWFhYWEtM2Y3ZTU3NzZlNDM0"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just to get these `ref_id` attributes values from the response it can be done using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor), the expression is as simple as:

```
entities.*.ref_id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)
- [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: Dmitri thank you so much for revert quickly, but I need them separately and my JSON response can be varies and where the `"type": "followUp"` can appear in the end of the JSON file

Comment: So cannot rely on the index value, so search `ref_id` where "type": "followUp", something like this

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this, as a JSON extractor.

`$..[?(@.type == "recall")].ref_id`

`$..[?(@.type == "followUp")].ref_id`